# htaccess removing folder from request path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am working on a projet and we have a folder "test" which hosts the whole page.
I want to have it, that it can be accessed by domain.com instead of domain.com/test

Normally I would just have the domain use test as a root folder but the cms wrote all images in the documents to domain.com/test but of course, if test is the root the images at domain.com/test (= test/test) can not be found. How can I fix this without editing all the images?

Can I just specify via htaccess that domain.com/test is supposed to look inside domain.com?

Thanks

**// Edit: Solution**

Thanks to the help I got the solution now my code is the following.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /test/$1 [L]
```

Thanks again, you saved my day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteCond {%REQUEST_URI} !^/test
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1 [L]
```

Should do it (not tested!). The first rule checks whether the /test/ folder is already accessed, and if so it skips the second rule. The second rule rewrites every URI to add /test/ before it.

Comment: Yeah, but I think I need it the other way around. domain.com/test/image.jpg needs to be change to domain.com/image.jpg
Or are you saying I should let the domain go to domain.com and use your code to go into the subfolder?

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean now. That makes it a bit more complicated... i'll see if I can find a solution

Comment: Okay, it nearly worked, my solution now is the following. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /test/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /test/%1 [L]
```